# Metal kernel -- 24-bit chicanery

Tags: metal

Below is my kernel.  It works wonderfully if both the input and output buffers contain RGBA-32 bit pixel data.  I've made this kernel slightly inefficient to show Metal's seeming ineptitude in dealing with 24-bit data.

(I previously had this working with the input and output buffers being declared as containing uint32_t data)

```
kernel void stripe_Kernel(device const uchar *inBuffer [[ buffer(0) ]],
                          device uchar4 *outBuffer [[ buffer(1) ]],
                          device const ushort *imgWidth  [[ buffer(2) ]],
                          device const ushort *imgHeight [[ buffer(3) ]],
                          device const ushort *packWidth  [[ buffer(4) ]],
                          uint2 gid [[ thread_position_in_grid ]])
{
    const ushort imgW  = imgWidth[0];
    const ushort imgH  = imgHeight[0];
    const ushort packW = packWidth[0];  // eg. 2048

    uint32_t posX = gid.x;  // eg. 0...2047
    uint32_t posY = gid.y;  // eg. 0...895

    uint32_t sourceX = ((int)(posY/imgH)*packW + posX) % imgW;
    uint32_t sourceY = (int)(posY%imgH);
    uint32_t ptr = (sourceY*imgW + sourceX)*4;  // this is for 32-bit data
    uchar4 pixel = uchar4(inBuffer[ptr],inBuffer[ptr+1],inBuffer[ptr+2],255);
    outBuffer[posY*packW + posX] = pixel;
}
```

I should mention that the inBuffer has been allocated as follows:

```
unsigned char *diskFrame;
posix_memalign((void *)&diskFrame,0x4000,imgHeight*imgWidth*4);
```

Now... if I actually have 24-bit data in there, and use multipliers of 3 (wherever I have 4), I get a entirely black image.

**What's with that?**

Comment: You've got integer division (`posY/imgH`) that's presumably always evaluating to 0. Also, how are you determining that the resulting buffer is "a[n] entirely black image"? The bug may be there.

Comment: The PosY/imgH behaviour is fine as I precisely want this truncated value (posY is typically much larger than imgH). BTW... this code works if I keep my inBuffer 32-bit aligned (even though it is only 75% used containing 24-bit data) and pass that in to the kernel shader.  Otherwise, it fails.  Thanks again for being helpful, Ken.

Comment: For the 24-bit format, are you using `packed_uchar3` for `outBuffer`? You need to. Non-packed `uchar3` has 4-byte size and alignment. I don't know what happens if you attempt an unaligned write.

Comment: 24-bit on the inBuffer which I treat as individual bytes on the read, not as a uchar3 of any sort; I'm using uchar4 on the outBuffer (R,G,B,A).  The above code works if the inBuffer is w*h*4 bytes like the outBuffer.  It might be a tad faster with packed uchar3.

Comment: I just changed the inBuffer to be packed_uchar3 of the proper size -- and then did "packed_uchar3 pixelIn = inBuffer[sourceY*imgW + sourceX];" and then "uchar4 pixel = uchar4((uchar)pixelIn[0],(uchar)pixelIn[1],(uchar)pixelIn[2],(uchar)0xff);" just before doing "outBuffer[posY*packW + posX] = pixel;".  Same issue.